# Can't get a variable to work in javascript

Tags: javascript

It's quite simple, I'm sure. I'm just trying to use Google Charts to create a map of information slightly off from it's intended purpose.

I'm basing if off of the Regions Chart [(Documentation Here)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Regions) [(Configuration Options Here)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options).

[This jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5hzqk7o1/) is identical to the documentation, except I've added `legend: 'none'` to the options on line 15 to remove the legend bar from the map

[This jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5hzqk7o1/1/) has the html pieces that I want so that I can enter multiple lines when hovering over a country. The problem is that `options` (now on line 19) isn't working. The bar is showing in the lower left. If I place `options` before `{tooltip: {isHtml: true}}`, then the bar goes away, but the html doesn't work. Clearly I'm doing something wrong here, I just don't know what. Please help.

Comment: Why is this question so heavily downvoted? Looks like this user has a genuine problem and does his best to explain it. Not like (s)he is asking y'all to do his homework.

Comment: Thank you. If I asked the question poorly, I'll gladly accept suggestions on improving it.

Comment: I just hope the somebody who downvotes you bothers enough to comment or flag the question... Seems ok to me, but cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) the GeoChart call takes two parameters and not three. The options should be a single object as the second parameter. You should combine all your options into your one options variable.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        }
    };
    chart.draw(data, options);        
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed that part.